# Symfony2 ondelete set Null

Tags: php, symfony, foreign-keys, constraints, symfony-2.5

I'm new with symfony2, and I started a project of blog. This project has two entities, one of posts (`Noticia`) and one with comments (`Comentario`).
I need to delete a post but I can't because of the relationship with comments.

Here is my attribute:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Noticia", inversedBy="comentarios", onDelete="SET NULL")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="noticia_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $noticia;
```

---

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comentario", mappedBy="noticia")
 */
private $comentarios = array();
```

I tried to put `onDelete="SET NULL"` but, when I updated my database with doctrine: `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I got this error:

```
The annotation @ORM\ManyToOne declared on property Noticia 
Bundle\Entity\Comentario\::$noticia does not have a property named "onDelete".
Avaible properties: targetEntity, cascade, fetch, inversedBy
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the **onDelete="SET NULL"** should be part of the *JoinColumn* annotation, not the *ManyToOne* annotation.

Comment: Also, after you make this change, be sure to update your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

One Way would be to search for all comments with the article relationship, you want to delete. 
So first delete all the comments, than the article itself.
That a the eaysiest way without changing the annotation.

Comment: I know, but, what is the "right way"?? Delete a post with a lot of comments is really a "NON best practicing"??

Comment: I feel like onDelete="CASCADE" is appropriate here.  If the Post is gone, do you want to keep the Comments?  If not, allow the deletion of the Post to cascade to also delete its Comments.